# Hosting Data on a Server

Tags: request, hosting, server-side

just a simple question, but it's been driving me mad, as I don't really know how to word it.

I want to be able to just send a simple post request to a server, and that server just returns back some data like plain text, a simple WWW request.

Where do I start for making a server that can do that? I also want to be able to upload revised data. FTP doesn't seem to be the thing that I want, and DB's seem to require authentication.

Thanks :)

Comment: So, you want your own server?

Comment: I can get hosting off x10hosting, but then I'm just swamped with 50 different types of php, sql and apache, but assume I have a server, and I just need to get some stuff onto it

Comment: And your server have to be online? I don't recommend that...

Comment: How should I go about this then? I've got a client program that needs to get data from a web server (as it's a web based application)

Comment: See the answer below.. I don't know another solution right now..

Answer (score 0):

Just install Apache or NGINX. IF you are using windows, then install IIS.